# Calculate the total of lesson hours (hours & minutes) of courses that take several days

Tags: mysql

I have got a mysql table that holds courses schedules / course hours. Some courses take several days. Now I would like to calculate the total of lesson hours (hours & minutes) per course. The table is named cm_courses_times_and_venues. Can any one help me with this ? I use PHP but if the calculcations could be handled in a mysql statement that would be excellent. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
course_id | course_start        | course_end
182       | 2018-04-09 08:45:00 | 2018-04-09 11:59:59
182       | 2018-04-09 13:00:00 | 2018-04-09 17:45:59
182       | 2018-04-10 08:45:00 | 2018-04-09 11:59:59
182       | 2018-04-10 13:00:00 | 2018-04-09 17:45:59
182       | 2018-04-11 08:45:00 | 2018-04-09 11:59:59
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query, I haven't tested but it should work:

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,course_end,course_start ) ) ) AS totalTime,  course_id from tblcourse group by course_id
```

in case time is More than 24 Hours, we can cast it to String :

```
SELECT  cast(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,course_end,course_start ) ) ) AS CHAR) AS totalTime,  course_id from tblcourse group by course_id
```

SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3cb79/2/0

In case u dont want total times for each course:

```
SELECT  cast(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,course_end,course_start ) )  AS CHAR) AS totalTime,  course_id from tblcourse
```

Comment: No Need for Time_TO_SEC as we have already getting times in SECONDS form TIMESTAMPDIFF.

Answer (score 0):

TIMEDIFF should do the work

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("2018-04-09 11:59:59","2018-04-09 08:45:00" );
```